# position: sticky; not working inside container with overflow: auto;

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2b383e;
}

.root {
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  --sidebar-width: 288px;
  display: flex;
  background: #141721;
}

.sidebar {
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  background: #1c202e;
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  height: 400px;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  width: calc(100% - var(--sidebar-width));
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: #4b49a0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>
<div class="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">footer</footer>
```

But my `.sidebar` does not work correctly and is not sticky. This behavior is because the `.root` element has the `overflow: auto;` property. But, I don't have permission to make changes inside CSS higher than the `.container` element.

How I can fix it without changing the `.root` element?

Comment: if you cannot remove overflow:auto then it's impossible unless you make that element scrollable

Comment: overflow auto shouldnt be a problem actually, as long as its high enough. what exactly is the problem, how is sidebar behaving vs your expected behavior? what exactly is the top var?

Comment: @Alex .sidebar is a container for left navigation menu. I want that it keep sticky while scrolling main page that named as .content. But now .sidebar is not sticky and has scroll together with .content

Comment: sticky needs its parent to have a height - cant you set a fixed height, or 100%? maybe create a fiddle or codepen to try it

Comment: @Alex I was add code snippet to discussion

Comment: @Alex check again please

Comment: i dont find a solution to get it to work, the overflow seems to make it impossible. when the container has a fixed height it works